# Java method returning type of generic type of generic used at class

Tags: java, generics

This is simple structure of code i wanna realize:

```
public class B {}
public class A<X extends B> {
    X x;
    public A(X x) {this.x = x;}
    public X getX() {return x;}
}
public class C<A> {
    public A getA() {return null;}       
    public A<T> T getGenericXOfA() {return getA().getX();}
}
```

I wanna to my class C by using method 'getGenericXOfA' returns type used at generic parameter of class A. 
Is that even possible at Java? I wanna do something like that:

```
public class C<A<X>> {
    public A getA() {return null;}       
    public X getGenericXOfA() {return getA().getX();}
}
```

or like that?:

```
public class C<A> {
    public A getA() {return null;}       
    public A<T> T getGenericXOfA() {return getA().getX();}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a raw type of the `A` when you need to generalise it by `X` which extends `B`:

```
class C<X extends B> {

    public A<X> getA() { ... }

    public X getGenericXOfA() {
        return getA().getX();
    }

}
```

Actually, you are playing with names of generic parameters. They don't matter and can't refer to existing classes.

If you want the same generic type like another class has, you should repeat the same template.

Comment: If they don't reffer I cannot to do some like that at more wealthier clasess like: public class A<X extends B, Y extends B> and at C<A> { Y getYofA() X getXofA()} or is there way to do that?

Comment: @TheTonsOfCode, you can't. if `C<A>` is not parametrised by `X` and `Y`, the code won't compile. They are just names and have no relation to the class `A` and its generic params `X`, `Y`

Comment: @TheTonsOfCode, If you explained what you are trying to achieve, I would recommend a kind of workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
public class C<X extends B, Y extends A<X>> {
    public Y getA() {return ... }       
}
```